# How to create a story using common action but custom object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I create a new story using common action but a custom object. for e.g. I would like to create a story which tells that:

> **`userX` followed a `topicY` at `myApp`**

So I need to create a story using common action but custom object. But **I don't see the common actions listed when I go about creating a new story** through

```
 Open Graph > Stories > Create a new Story
```

So how do I create a story using common actions ?

Comment: The follow action is for following FB users only. You will have to create your own action – and use a different name for it.

Comment: in my app, people follow certain topic or person, so I want to post that activity to FB. Can't I anyway publish a story saying `personX followed TopicY`?